# Adding a remove button on a JavaScript object array that is looped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript object that has this structure:

```
var spouse = {
  s_name: { value: spouse_name, label: "Name" },
  s_nric: { value: spouse_nric_passport, label: "NRIC/Passport" },
  s_dob: { value: spouse_date_of_birth, label: "Date of Birth" },
  s_occupation: { value: spouse_occupation, label: "Occupation" },
  s_weight: { value: spouse_weight, label: "Weight" },
  s_height: { value: spouse_height, label: "Height" }
};
```

I am currently iterating through it like this:

```
$.each(spouses, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value);
  $.each(value, function(int_key, int_value) {
    console.log(int_key);
    console.log(int_value.value);
    console.log(int_value.label);
    $("#spouse_data").append(
      "<div class='col-sm-4'><label>" +
        int_value.label +
        "</label><input type='text' readonly class='form-control' value=" +
        int_value.value +
        "></div>"
    );
  });
});
```

What this does is place the elements into dynamically generated html elements. However, I am unsure of how I can place the remove function. At the moment if I place it within the loop, each row of data within a structure will contain a remove function instead of a general remove function.

How can I change this so that I can add a general remove function? Or is there a better way to print out this structure onto the screen?

Comment: So you want to have a single remove button, is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah. And if you have a better way of displaying a javascript object in html that would be great also

Comment: What do you mean by `a remove function instead of a general remove function`??

Comment: Add a button that calls the function `remove`. While rendering the list, add a checkbox and set the current index as the its ID. This checkbox, whenever checked, will call the function `markForRemoval` (`markForRemoval` basically adds the ID to an array, which is later used by `remove` method.) Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Sorry but if I add a checkbox about 6 checkboxes will be added due to my loop. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try the following way:

```js
var spousesArray = [{
  s_name:{value:"spouse_name",label:"Name"},
  s_nric:{value:"spouse_nric_passport",label:"NRIC/Passport"},
  s_dob:{value:"spouse_date_of_birth",label:"Date of Birth"},
  s_occupation:{value:"spouse_occupation",label:"Occupation"},
  s_weight:{value:"spouse_weight",label:"Weight"},
  s_height:{value:"spouse_height",label:"Height"}
},
{
  s_name:{value:"spouse_name",label:"Name2"},
  s_nric:{value:"spouse_nric_passport",label:"NRIC/Passport2"},
  s_dob:{value:"spouse_date_of_birth",label:"Date of Birth2"},
  s_occupation:{value:"spouse_occupation",label:"Occupation2"},
  s_weight:{value:"spouse_weight",label:"Weight2"},
  s_height:{value:"spouse_height",label:"Height2"}
}];

$.each(spousesArray, function(i, spouses){
  var classN = 'parent-' + i;
  var removeBtn = "<button onclick=remove('" +classN+ "')>Remove</button>";
  $("#spouse_data").append("<div class='" +classN+ "'><div>")
  $.each(spouses,function(key,value){
    $("."+classN).append("<div class='col-sm-4'><label>"+value.label+"</label><input type='text' readonly class='form-control' value="+value.value+"></div>");  
  });
  $("."+classN).append(removeBtn);
});

function remove(el){
  $('.' + el).remove();
  var position = el.split('-')[1];
  spousesArray.splice(position,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spouse_data"></div>
```

Comment: Thats great. But I want to remove the entire structure. This structure will be added to an array

Comment: @JianYA, I understand you want to remove everything generated by a single remove button.....but can not understand `This structure will be added to an array`........

Comment: spouses is an object that will be added to an array. So an array of spouses. I cannot remove only one item within the spouse object. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @JianYA, you might see the the updated answer....if it helps you solve your problem.....thanks

Comment: does this remove it from the array as well?

Comment: @JianYA, no, right now it does not.....do you want to remove this from the array as well?

Comment: yeah that would be great because it should be reading from an array.

Comment: @JianYA, then how would you get back the removed spouse again if you want to? Personally I think that is not logical....

Comment: I have a form that I use to add the spouse back

Comment: @JianYA, thank you for accepting the answer... may I request you to upvote as well....thanks.